Not receiving push notifications on ios from firebase messaging
I have followed all the steps that were needed to perform on apple developer account and firebase messaging but still not getting notifications on IOS. I am sending notifications through FCM tests.
It works fine on android. The provisioning profile is added on XCode as well as the required capabilities.
I am using these versions:
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.5.0",

async function requestUserPermission() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
  }
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {

      const apnsToken = await messaging().getAPNSToken();
      console.log(apnsToken, '------');
      if (apnsToken) {
        await messaging().setAPNSToken(apnsToken);
        console.log('APNs Token:', apnsToken);
      } else {
        console.log('Failed to get APNs token');
      }
    }

    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    console.log(fcmToken, '-----');
    //toaster.custom(fcmToken, fcmToken);
    if (fcmToken) {
      setFcmToken(fcmToken);
      console.log('FCM Token:', fcmToken);
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to get FCM token');
    }
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  requestUserPermission();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
    console.log('background', type, detail);
    switch (type) {
      case EventType.PRESS:
        console.log(
          'send in data such as feed or other name and based on that redirect to post or screen',
        );
        break;
    }
  });
  
  notifee.onForegroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
    console.log('foreground', type, detail);
    switch (type) {
      case EventType.PRESS:
        console.log(
          'send in data such as feed or other name and based on that redirect to post or screen',
        );
        break;
    }
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async remoteMessage => {
    
    console.log('on notification opened app', remoteMessage);
    onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  });

  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  });
  
  const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
   
    console.log('on message', remoteMessage);
    onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);

const onMessageReceived = (message: FirebaseMessagingTypes.RemoteMessage | undefined) => {
  Platform.OS === 'android' &&
    Toast.show({
      type: 'customNotification',
      props: { text1: `${message?.notification?.body}` },
      position: 'top',
      swipeable: true,
      autoHide: false,
      onPress: () => {
        Toast.hide();

        console.log('on press, redirect to page');
      },
    });

  const notifeeData = {
    body: message?.notification?.body,
    data: message?.data,
    android: {
      channelId: 'default',
      actions: [
        {
          title: 'Mark as Read',
          pressAction: { id: 'read' },
        },
      ],
      // smallIcon: 'ic_large_icon',
      color: '#FFDE18',
      badgeIconType: AndroidBadgeIconType.LARGE,
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
      pressAction: {
        id: 'read',
      },
    },
    ios: {
      foregroundPresentationOptions: {
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
        banner: true,
        list: true,
      },
      actions: [
        {
          id: 'mark-as-read',
          title: 'Mark as Read',
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  notifee.displayNotification(notifeeData);
};

